# Issue with configuring Serdes for Kafka Streams

Tags: java, spring-boot, apache-kafka, deserialization, apache-kafka-streams

I put a json object to my "commits" topic. I want to consume messages using Kafka Streams, but there is an error

```
@Configuration
@EnableKafka
@EnableKafkaStreams
public class AnalyzerConfiguration {
    @Bean(name = KafkaStreamsDefaultConfiguration.DEFAULT_STREAMS_CONFIG_BEAN_NAME)
    public KafkaStreamsConfiguration kStreamsConfigs() {
        Map<String, Object> props = new HashMap<>();
        props.put(StreamsConfig.APPLICATION_ID_CONFIG, "test-streams");
        props.put(StreamsConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG, "localhost:9092");
        props.put(StreamsConfig.DEFAULT_KEY_SERDE_CLASS_CONFIG, Serdes.String().getClass().getName());
        props.put(StreamsConfig.DEFAULT_VALUE_SERDE_CLASS_CONFIG, commitSerde().getClass());

        return new KafkaStreamsConfiguration(props);
    }

    @Bean
    public Serde<Commit> commitSerde() {
        return Serdes.serdeFrom(new JsonSerializer<>(), new JsonDeserializer<>(Commit.class));
    }

    @Bean
    public KStream<String, Commit> kStream(StreamsBuilder builder) {
        KStream<String, Commit> stream = builder.stream("commits", Consumed.with(Serdes.String(), commitSerde()));

        KTable<String, Long> commitsCount = stream
                .mapValues(Commit::getAuthorName)
                .selectKey((key, word) -> word)
                .groupByKey()
                .count(Materialized.as("Counts"));

        commitsCount.toStream().to("commits-count", Produced.with(Serdes.String(), Serdes.Long()));

        return stream;
    }
}
```

Log says:

Exception in thread "test-streams-469f5ee6-d0de-472e-a602-a7b6d11f2e1c-StreamThread-1" org.apache.kafka.streams.errors.StreamsException: Failed to configure value serde class org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.Serdes$WrapperSerde

Caused by: org.apache.kafka.common.KafkaException: Could not find a public no-argument constructor for org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.Serdes$WrapperSerde

Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodException

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is the registration of the `StreamsConfig.DEFAULT_VALUE_SERDE_CLASS_CONFIG`. First, this is not needed in your example, as you specify the value serde in the `Consumed` you use when creating the KStream. You could just leave out the default serde.

If you register a class as a default serde, Kafka Streams will at some point create an instance of that class via reflection. That calls the default (no-argument) constructor of that class. In your example a org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.Serdes$WrapperSerde class will be used from `Serdes.serdeFrom(new JsonSerializer<>(), new JsonDeserializer<>(Commit.class))`. This class has no such constructor, which causes the exception.

If you want to register a default serde for your `Commit` type, you need to wrap it into a small class:

```java
public class CommitSerde extends WrapperSerde<Commit> {

    public CommitSerde() {
        super(new JsonSerializer<>(), new JsonDeserializer<>(Commit.class));
    }
}
```

This class should be suitable to be registered as default value serde using `props.put(StreamsConfig.DEFAULT_VALUE_SERDE_CLASS_CONFIG, CommitSerde.class.getName());` in your example.